# I have to run "/bin/bash --login" everytime to use rake/rails commands?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bash, ruby-on-rails-4, rake

whenever I switch directory in my terminal, I have to run the command "/bin/bash --login" before I can run rails/rake related commands. If I don't, I get an error saying "the program "rails" can be found in the following packages: ..."

Any advice?

Comment: Did you alter your bash profile in some way when setting up rails?

Comment: Are you doing something crazy like setting a path to the directory containing `rails` relative to your current directory?

Comment: No I just followed a guide using RVM to install rails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default some servers do not allow this due to permissions reason. You can place this in 
`~/.bashrc` and it will automatically work when you open a new terminal

As per bash man page.

> When an interactive shell that is not a login shell is started, bash
>   reads and executes commands from ~/.bashrc, if that file exists. This
>   may be inhibited by using the --norc option. The --rcfile file option
>   will force bash to read and execute commands from file instead of
>   ~/.bashrc.
>
> When bash is started non-interactively, to run a shell script, for
>   example, it looks for the variable BASH_ENV in the environment,
>   expands its value if it appears there, and uses the expanded value as
>   the name of a file to read and execute. Bash behaves as if the
>   following command were executed:
>
> if [ -n "$BASH_ENV" ]; then . "$BASH_ENV"; fi  but the value of the
>   PATH variable is not used to search for the file name.

The file is just shell commands. It is typically used to change prompts, set environment variables, and define shell procedures. Traditionally, the file .profile is used for this purpose, but bash has so many extensions that it needs its own startup file for users that want to put bashisms in startup files.

Comment: Sorry for being a total noob, but what is .bashsrc?

Answer (score 0):

Easy solution:

Just open terminal. GO to Edit menu from terminal navigation bar, Select "Profile Preferences", It will open "edit profile pop-up". Select "Title and Command" button and "check Run Command as login shell"

ctrl + alt + t -> Edit -> Profile Preferences -> Title and Command -> Check Run command as login shell

Close the terminal and open again. Next time you don't need to  "/bin/bash --login"